# Как заполнить теги <span> значениями из объекта при совпадении id тега и ключа объекта?

Tags: javascript, html

Я новичок от слова "совсем"). Пытаюсь реализовать следующее: есть объект. Есть несколько span. Нужно перебрать все span по id и если id совпадает со значением ключа в объекте- присвоить ему соответствующее значение.
Не догоняю совсем.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="MyText"></span>
    <span id="MySelect2"></span>
    <span id="MySelect3"></span>    
</body>
<script>
    let MyObject = {MyText: "2", MySelect2: "5", MySelect3: "8"}
    let Span = document.querySelectorAll("span");
    for (key in MyObject){
    for (var i =0;  i < Span.length; i++){
        let ID = Span[i].getAttribute("id")
        if (какое-то условие) {Span[i].innerHTML= MyObject[значение]}
    }   
    }   

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая, что на странице может быть чуть больше span, чем ключей у объекта, есть смысл наоборот - по ключам искать все элементы:

```js
let obj = {
  MyText: "2",
  MySelect2: "5",
  MySelect3: "8"
};

for( let id in obj ){
  let span = document.querySelector("span#" + id);
                                      ↑
  // Селектор уже требует, чтобы это был именно span с таким id
  if( span ){ // Если такого элемента нет, вернется null → false
    span.textContent = obj[ id ];
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="MyText"></span>
<span id="MySelect2"></span>
<span id="MySelect3"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень помогли! С Новым Годом!)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let MyObject = {
  MyText: "2",
  MySelect2: "5",
  MySelect3: "8"
};
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function(el) {
  if (MyObject[el.id])
    el.innerHTML = MyObject[el.id];
});
```

```html
<span id="MyText"></span>
<span id="MySelect2"></span>
<span id="MySelect3"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень помогли! С Новым Годом!)